# Line below and to the right of a button

Tags: css

[image]

You can see that the buttons have one darkish line at the bottom and to the right. How can I achieve this effect? Right now all I have is

```
#button {
background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
#button {
  border: none; // clear default button border
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray; // set bottom border
  border-right: 2px solid gray; // set right border
}
```